# Javascript regex url for domain or ip address

Tags: javascript, regex

I am needing to check the url entered on a page and its still matching http:// only string. I want it to fail if user only enters `http://`

Regex pattern
`^(https?:\/\/)(www\.)?(([a-zA-Z]+)?(\.[a-zA-z]{2,6})?)((\d{1,3}\.){3}(\d{1,3}){1})?$/gm`

tests:

```
google.com  <---- fails as it should
https://google.com  <---- Pass
https:google.com  <---- fails as it should
www.cool.com.au  <---- fails as it should
https://asdsds.Com
http://a  <---- Pass
https://  <---- Pass **BUT SHOULD FAIL**
http://10.10.10.00  <---- Pass
http://www.cool.com  <---- Pass
https://123123.asd  <---- fails as it should
http://www.cool.com.au/ersdfs  <---- fails as it should
http://www.cool.com.au/ersdfs?dfd=dfgd@s=1  <---- fails as it should
http://www.cool.com:81/index.html  <---- fails as it should
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point here is to add `(?!$)` after `^(https?:\/\/)`, it will fail the match if there is end of string/line immediately after the protocol part.

You can use

```js
^(?:https?:\/\/)(?!$)(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z]*(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})?(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CSC8Fm/1).

Note the `{1}` is redundant and need removing. `[a-zA-z]` (that does not match only letters) is most probably a typo, you must have meant `[a-zA-Z]`.

I removed unnecessary capturing groups and converted capturing ones into non-capturing to get cleaner regex match structure, only use capturing mechnanism when you need to actually get the match parts.